# if $-1<a<1$ and $-1<b<1$ how to prove that $(a+b)/(1+ab) $is also always between $-1$ and $1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I am trying to prove closure (among other things) a on algebraic structure $(A,*)$ where:

$$A=(-1,1) ⊂ R,\ a*b=(a+b)/(1+ab)$$ (note that "*" here is NOT multiplication)

So I have to prove that if:

$$-1< a <1 \ \text{and} -1< b <1$$

The following is also true:
$$-1<(a+b)/(1+ab)<1$$

I tried to "solve" it but all I could come up with is relation $|a+b|<1+ab$ for the above to be true.Truth is I am stuck.

I would highly appreciate if someone could just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: $a+b - (1+ab) = (a-1)(1-b)$, and similarly $a+b + 1+ab = (a+1)(b+1)$

Comment: Complementary hint : if you want to bound a quantity $\frac{x}{y}$ (here you have $x=a+b$ and $y=1-ab$), look at the sign of $y$ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different hint from the comments. You could square what you have already got and try to prove $(a+b)^2\lt(1+ab)^2$, which gets rid of the absolute value.

Answer (score 3):

Directly and double inequality:

$$\frac{a+b}{1+ab}>-1\iff\frac{a+b+ab+1}{1+ab}>0\iff \frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{ab+1}>0$$

and we're done since $\;a>-1\,,\,b>-1\;,\;ab>-1\;$ (this last one is the most interesting, imo)

Now try to prove in a similar way that

$$\frac{a+b}{ab+1}<1\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an overkill!

This is the speed summation formula in the special theory of relativity. Assume speed of light $c=1$. If $a$ is speed of observer 2 with respect to observer 1, and $b$ is speed of observer 3 with respect to observer 2. Then the speed of observer 3 with respect to observer 1 is $(a+b)/(1+ab)$. And all of them are between $-1$ and $1$.

Another way, let: $a=\tanh x$, $b=\tanh y$ then $\tanh (x+y)= (a+b)/(1+ab)$ and all are between $-1$ and $1$.